# Allocating (or adjusting) points to closest polygon QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, point

Hi I've recently posed a [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/325947/count-points-belonging-to-a-country-but-outside-of-country-polygon-coastal) on how to create buffer areas for coastal borders of country polygons in order to match all my points (of which many are just outside country polygon borders) to a country. However, expanding country polygons through buffer zones does not provide a reliable solution.
Using higher quality global shapefiles helped a little but did not work for all my points.

Is there a way to adjust points to the closest polygon (e.g. change their spatial location to sit within the closest polygon)? Or is there another way to reliable count all points either within or next to the closest polygon? All my points have to be associated with one country, even if they sit 1 or 2km outside the polygon boundaries.

I've played around with NNJoin a little, but couldn't find a way to get it to work. Which doesn't say much as i'm a beginner.

Comment: Try **Snap geometries to layer** tool. It will snap input points to the country polygons (the reference layer).

Comment: Thanks, Kazuhito. This almost worked. However, it aligns the points with the polygon edges. So afterwards I can't perform Count in Polygon operations as points on edges don't seem to be counted as within a polygon. Any other ways how to move geometry into a polygon instead of just to the edge?

Comment: I understand you are using `within`. Try `intersects` instead.

Comment: You could take an inward buffer of your country layer (IE use the buffer tool with a negative number for the buffer distance). Snap the points to the inward buffered-layer, and they will be inside the corresponding country polygon.

Comment: That's a great suggestions, csk! I couldn't find 'intersects' in the count points in polygon function in QGIS, so i'll go with your suggestion. Thanks both for your suggestions!